# Two std::map's whose values are each other's iterators?

Tags: c++, dictionary, incomplete-type

I need two `std::map`s whose values point to each others' elements for performance reasons.
This is to allow constant-time insertion/removal of one's elements when the other is already traversed.

What is the fastest way to implement this correctly in C++? Note that the obvious approach doesn't work since the type of the second map is incomplete before its iterator can be declared as the type of the value of the first map. Are [Variants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant.html) my only option, or is there a better solution?

Comment: must they be iterators? could they simply be pointers to the value?

Comment: @RichardHodges: Can pointers satisfy the constraints I stated in the second sentence?

Comment: difficult to say without more information. A void pointer to the value_type could be cast to yield a key.... but I know that's not what you want. Perhaps it's time to split concerns? storage and indexing?

Comment: @RichardHodges: Can you elaborate on how to split concerns to solve this? Are you saying I should have a third container whose elements points back to the elements of these two?

Comment: I'm beginning to think that way, but without more information it's difficult to advise. Note that the storage container itself needn't have a key. A linked-list perhaps?

Comment: or maybe you can get constant-time more easily by using an unordered_map. Again, difficult to know without knowing more about the problem domain.

Comment: @RichardHodges: I see. I can think of ways to do it with a third container, I wasn't really trying to go that route due to the perceived performance hit, but thinking more about it, it seems possible to do that via 2 extra vectors (one to hold the iterators, the other to hold a stack of open indices in the first one, with the iterators holding indices into the first vector). I kind of like it actually, thanks for the idea. (Regarding `unordered_map`, it won't work since I actually need the ordering... I basically need all the guarantees provided by trees here.)

Comment: Great. I wouldn't worry about the performance hit of one extra indirection. if it gets that critical (it won't!) then its probably time to write a custom map.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you intend to use this structure? For example I am wondering how you will add your first element to one of your two maps. What will be its mapped value?

Comment: @Galik: Its mapped value would initially be just a dummy iterator (e.g. `other_container.end()`), it doesn't matter if it's invalid because once both are inserted I can change both.

Comment: I still think we need to know more about how you intend to use the structure and how the cross-referencing works in order to begin to think about solutions. Without knowing the actual problem, solutions are difficult to come up with.

Comment: @Galik: Honestly the details aren't as useful as you're imagining; the problem and its constraints are literally what I've stated and simplified everything down to. Rest assured the keys are all just pointer-sized as well; and there are no larger objects like strings involved anywhere. The idea of using a third container is a decent one, and I think it solves it here.

Answer (score 2):

You want mutually recursive types in a way that, as far as I know, can't be achieved with (forward) declarations.  But C++ offers another mean which is the famous CRTP:

```
#include <map>

template <typename T>
struct BidirMapHelper {
    struct ReverseElt {
        ReverseElt() {}
        ReverseElt(typename T::iterator p) : v(p) {}
        typename T::iterator v;
    };
    typedef std::map<int, ReverseElt> ReverseMap;
};

struct BidirMap: BidirMapHelper<BidirMap>
{
    struct DirectElt {
        DirectElt() {}
        DirectElt(ReverseMap::iterator p) : v(p) {}
        ReverseMap::iterator v;
    };
    typedef std::map<int, DirectElt> DirectMap;
    typedef DirectMap::iterator iterator;
};

typedef BidirMap::DirectMap DirectMap;
typedef BidirMap::ReverseMap ReverseMap;

int main () {
    DirectMap m1;
    ReverseMap m2;
    m1[0] = m2.end();
    m2[0] = m1.end();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles cleanly with g++ and clang++ under Linux, but I must admit that I'm not sure it does not depend on an implementation characteristic of the standard library such as having SCARY iterators.

Comment: +1, this is extremely clever and the kind of solution I was hoping for, but I'm quite surprised this compiles cleanly. Isn't `typename BidirMap::iterator` undefined when the type `BidirMapHelper<BidirMap>` instantiated in `ReverseElt`? Or is the instantiation of the type delayed because it is wrapped in `ReverseElt`?

Comment: That issue is not different than in most usages of the CRTP which depends on the availability during instantiation of a template of the parameter. But the more I think about it, the more I'm persuaded that it depend on implementation defined characteristics of std::map to provide the decoupling needed to make it works (usually the decoupling is provided by the fact that member function bodies are considered only when the class is no more incomplete).

Comment: In normal CRTP such usage of the dependent types is inside the member functions, and like you said, those aren't instantiated until they are used, at which point the type is complete. Over here it's in the member declarations, so that's why I'm confused why it should work...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler solution, which, however, is not guaranteed to compile for an arbitrary standard-compliant implementation of `std::map`. Yet it compiles with gcc 4.4.7 (which doesn't even support -std=c++11) and with gcc 5.x, gcc 6.1, clang 3.x and icc 13.0.1 (both with and without -std=c++11).

```
#include <map>

struct It1;
struct It2;

typedef std::map<int, It2> Map1;
typedef std::map<int, It1> Map2;

struct It2 : Map2::iterator
{
    It2() {}
    It2(Map2::iterator it) : Map2::iterator(it) {}
};

struct It1 : Map1::iterator
{
    It1() {}
    It1(Map1::iterator it) : Map1::iterator(it) {}
};

int main()
{
    Map1 m1;
    Map2 m2;

    m1[0] = m2.end();
    m2[0] = m1.end();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works with GCC, but is technically undefined behaviour, because you instantiate `std::map` with an incomplete type as the template argument.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I would not use the term *undefined behavior* here. Maybe, according to the standard, it is not guaranteed to compile, but that is not UB in its dangerous sense. If it compiles, it should work without problem.

Comment: As I said, it is **technically** undefined behaviour.